# Flip an image when a table cell is clicked, or the image itself is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to flip an arrow 180 degrees if a cell is clicked, or if the imaged itself is clicked.. Here's my code: Note: The image being flipped is the one in the first row with an ID of image1. I will be flipping all of the images once I get this first one working.

```
<thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align:left; padding-top: 20px;" width="10%" title="Sort by Symbol">Symbol <img src="/images/sort-arrow.jpg" title="Sort by Symbol" alt="Sort by Symbol" class="sort-right move-left bottom-image" id="image1"/></th>
                <th style="text-align:left;" width="20%" title="Sort by Company Name">Company<br><span class="move_right">Name</span> <img src="/images/sort-arrow.jpg" title="Sort by Company Name" alt="Sort by Company Name" class="sort-right move-left"/></th>
                <th style="text-align:center;" width="12%" title="Sort by Buy Date"><span class="center-text">Buy</span><br>Date <img title="Sort by Buy Date" src="/images/sort-arrow.jpg" alt="Sort by Buy Date"/></th>
                <th style="text-align:center;" width="10%" title="Sort by Buy Price"><span class="center-text">Buy</span><br>Price &nbsp;<img title="Sort by Buy Price" src="/images/sort-arrow.jpg" alt="Sort by Buy Price"/></th>
                <th style="text-align:center;" width="9%" title="Sort by Closed Price"><span class="center-text">Closed</span><br>Price &nbsp;<img title="Sort by Closed Price" src="/images/sort-arrow.jpg" alt="Sort by Closed Price"/></th>
                <th style="text-align:center;" width="9%" title="Sort by Closed Date"><span class="center-text">Closed</span><br>Date &nbsp;<img title="Sort by Closed Date" src="/images/sort-arrow.jpg" alt="Sort by Closed Date" /></th>
                <th style="text-align:center;" width="10%" title="Sort by Current Return"><span class="center-text">Total</span><br>Return &nbsp;<img title="Sort by Current Return" src="/images/sort-arrow.jpg" alt="Sort by Current Return"/></th>
        </thead>
```

And the Javascript:

```
$(function(event){
    $("table .title a").tooltip({ bodyHandler: function(event) { return $($(this).attr("href")).html(); }, showURL: false, track: true, delay: 0 });
});

var value = 0
$("#image1").rotate({ 
   bind: 
     { 
        click: function(){
            value +=180;
            $(this).rotate({ animateTo:value})
        }
     } 

});
```

I am using the [jQuery Rotate](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/) plugin

Any recommendations?

Just to reaffirm: The image should do a 180 degree flip if the image is clicked, or if the CELL in which the image is located is CLICKED.

Comment: your code is working fine http://jsfiddle.net/9FMks/1/

Comment: No you see, I want the image to rotate when they click inside the table cell to. Just to reaffirm: The image should rotate when they click the image, and or if they click the cell in which the image is located. @Manish

Comment: It is rotating when you click on the image

Comment: When you click the image, OR the cell it is in @Manish

Comment: you need to add $("#image1").rotate in th click [http://jsfiddle.net/9FMks/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/9FMks/2/)

Comment: You are the man! Submit that as the answer and I'll except it @AbrahamUribe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add the .rotate inside the "th" .click and preventPropagation on the image1 .click like this

```
var value = 0
$("th:first").click(function(){//you can add some class or id the first th or select only the first
    value +=180;
    $("#image1").rotate({ animateTo:value});//or $(this).find("img")
});
$("#image1").rotate({ 
   bind: 
     { 
        click: function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();//or the image will rotate 360
            value +=180;
            $(this).rotate({ animateTo:value})
        }
     } 

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9FMks/2/

Comment: Thanks! Question though, I am trying to implement this to the other columns, but when I add it to the other columns (change the value, id selector for the rows) it doesn't work... Can you use this example and make it work on two columns so I can see how you do it? Thanks for the help @AbrahamUribe